# Alternative to javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename);

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

I have some code:

```
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
...
..
.
String filename = "foo.xls"; // Where this can be any file name .doc, .pdf or whatever

String headerContentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename);
```

It seems javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap class is inside `rt.jar` which comes with JRE System library (jdk1.6.0_10) but not in jdk1.5.0

I would like to avoid the use of 1.6 libraries. Anyone knows an easy and quick alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes from the [activation](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/jaf/downloads/index.html) framework. This is included as standard in Java 6, but is also available as a separate download (for use with Java 1.4 and above)

Comment: Thanks. The ugly thing with Java is the feeling of adding million lines of code in libraries for just one simple function.

Comment: I think activation.jar is relatively concise, but I take your point!

Answer (score 2):

The particular class is actually part of the java bean s activation framework;

[JAF Download](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/jaf/downloads/index.html)

It should not be dependant on 1.6 as far as I know. So simply download the jar, and ensure you have the mimetypes.default available on your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I've used with success this project [SubLuna](http://sourceforge.net/projects/subluna/), it seems more complete than JAF. It uses this mime type collection : [Shared MIME Info Specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info) which is well maintained(of course you will have to replace the file that comes with the library).